# What is the name of a hole in the ice-covered lake

Tags: word-request

I live in the UK, and I asked a dozen people but no one has an answer.

What is the English word describing a hole in an ice-covered lake (cut, drilled or natural)? In Polish it is called `"przerębel`".

Example pictures:
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No single word exists in English.  We would say "a hole in the ice". One can speculate that winters in Britain are relatively mild, so such scenes don't happen.

> Want to go ice fishing? We're going to cut a hole in the ice and fish for trout that are still down below.

As a technical term "polynya" is used for an ice free region surrounded by pack ice in the arctic or antarctic (it is a borrowing from Russian).  The pictures above would not be called "polynya" - it is only for large areas of open water surrounded by sea ice.  Another sea-ice word is "lead" (rhymes with reed) which is a crack in the sea ice.  Again, this doesn't apply to your pictures.

Comment: *`"One can speculate that winters in Britain are relatively mild, so such scenes don't happen."`* Scotland?

Comment: Yes, winters in Scotland are relatively mild.  Certainly that is so in the Scottish islands.  Even inland, Glasgow is about 5 degrees warmer than Warsaw in the winter. Thick ice, as in your pictures, would be unusual.  When the Water of Leith froze in 2010 it was remarked as being a "very rare event". Most years the river is ice free

Comment: Actually, Kent can be of the colder parts of Britain in the winter.  It is more influenced by the cold continent

Comment: @JamesK - it was perishing in Sevenoaks the last time I was there.

Comment: Four children died in December 2022 after falling through the ice that covered a lake in Solihull, near Birmingham, UK.

Comment: Yes,  the ice that will cover a lake will often be too thin to support people's weight. These children didn't cut a hole in the ice,  probably they just wanted to try skating, with tragic results because winters in Britain are relatively mild and the ice may appear stronger than it actually is.

Answer (score 3):

James K's answer, *a hole in the ice*, can be shortened to [*an ice hole*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ice_hole)

> ice hole (plural *ice holes*)
>
> A hole in the ice of a frozen body of water, often man-made with the scope of fishing. (Wiktionary)

The expression "an ice hole" appears to be quite common in North America. I also found a TV reality show called *[Ice Holes](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3768324/)* that was aired way back in 2014. It is a special usage because it's not just any crack, small or large hole ora that appears on a frozen surface, it's a hole made specifically for fishing and for …brrrrrr swimming.

[image: man, half naked, taking a dip in an ice hole]

[Google images](https://www.google.com/search?q=an%20%22ice%20hole%22&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiE-a_02L_-AhU6pycCHTAdB98Q2-cCegQIABAA&oq=an%20%22ice%20hole%22&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzoECCMQJ1DCD1iBImDuJ2gAcAB4AIABtQGIAf0CkgEDMS4ymAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=-fpEZMSYCLrOnsEPsLqc-A0&bih=578&biw=1108) confirm that "ice hole" is widespread and commonly used, but some non-native speakers should be a little careful with the pronunciation, as it could be mistaken for  *asshole*. We wouldn't want that, would we? :)

Comment: The wiktionary page notes that it is a "translation hub" that is it is a page that exists only as a target for translation.  In principle we could form an endless variety of "A hole in the X is an X hole"  That is "ice hole" the use of "ice" as an attributive noun.  It isn't a word with any special significance.  We could have "cheese hole" or " "sock hole" and so on.

Comment: @JamesK I agree which is why I also included a link to Google images- the phrase "an ice hole" appears to be quite common in North America. I even found a TV reality show called [*Ice Holes*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3768324/) way back in 2014. It has a special significance because it's not just any small or large hole ora  crack that appears on a frozen surface, it's a hole made specifically for fishing and for ...brrrrrr swimming.